# cron-job.org Firebase Callable Function

Tags: firebase, cron, google-cloud-functions

I want to call a function every 5 mins to check that my site is operational, and be emailed if the server doesn't respond.

I have decided to use cron-job.org as it was recommended to me by a colleague, and had the features that I needed. My function is a https.onCall function.

[image]

I have set it up using the above configuration using the rules outlined here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference

but my cloud function is saying this in the console "Function execution took 10 ms, finished with status code: 400". Can anyone point me in the right direction? Can't see what I am doing wrong. I can see that error code 400 is a badly formatted request, but why?

The function is set to just return if there is no params.

Comment: If you use an HTTP function instead of a callable function, this will be much easier. There is no advantage (and lots of hassle) to using a callable function if you're not calling it directly from a Firebase client app. If you really want to use a callable function outside of an app, you will have to implement the full spec, which you are not doing now.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I was wanting to use a callable function as I only have callable functions in my app, no plain old http ones. I like the idea of calling a real production method. Is there documentation on how to implement the full spec? Unless I am missing something I have set the Content-Type and required data body value.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference for the specification.